# some Images won't load - android openGL textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-resources

I have an GlSurfaceView that is drawing a square that i am trying to texturize with a image.png  I have played with two different png files both in the same drawable folder..  When i reference one it loads just fine but if i switch the R.image.png to the other, my sqaure just turns white..  can anyone help?  below is my square class, and my glView.

Square:

```
    package com.eliddell.AR;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.ByteOrder;
    import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
    import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.opengl.GLUtils;

    public class Square {

       private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;   // buffer holding the vertices

       private float vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,        // V1 - bottom left
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,        // V2 - top left
        1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,        // V3 - bottom right
        1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f         // V4 - top right

};

private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;  // buffer holding the texture coordinates
private float texture[] = {
        // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
        0.0f, 1.0f,     // top left     (V2)
        0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
        1.0f, 1.0f,     // top right    (V4)
        1.0f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)

};


public Square() {

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texture);
    textureBuffer.position(0);

}
/** The texture pointer */
private int[] textures = new int[1];

public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    // loading texture
    InputStream is =                                     context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.android);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.android);

    // generate one texture pointer
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    // ...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // create nearest filtered texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Clean up
    bitmap.recycle();
}
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    // bind the previously generated texture
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // Point to our buffers
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Set the face rotation
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    // Point to our vertex buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

}

   }
```

and my GLSurfaceView and Render:

```
    package com.eliddell.AR;

    import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
    import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
    import android.opengl.GLU;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
    import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

    public class GLLayer extends GLSurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback, Renderer {

private Context context;
private Square square;   // the triangle to be drawn


public GLLayer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.square = new Square();

    // settings for translucent glView
    this.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    // set render to inline 
    this.setRenderer(this);

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // clear Screen and Depth Buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Reset the Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    // Drawing
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);     // move 5 units INTO the screen
                                            // is the same as moving the camera 5 units away
    square.draw(gl);                      // Draw the triangle

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
    height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
    }
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix
    //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix


}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig arg1) {
    // Load the texture for the square
    square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    //Black Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

    //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propably your texture dosent have power of two dimensions.
Opengl can load only textures witch have pot(power of two) size like:  32X32 , 64X64 , 128X128 .....  and not 36X36 , 48X48 ....

Change your image size.

Comment: ruh roh.. you are right, as you know..  This brings up a concern though.  My plan going forward was to texture the square with images from the web.. is this a problem?  is it even possible?

Comment: Well in this case(if i understand right)you need fisrt to check if image from web is pot size  and if it isn't you need to resize the bitmap before you load it to opengl  see this for how to resize the bitmap  http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/

Comment: Ok so now i am trying to create png files from photoshop cs5 that can be used as textures.  i have created an image that is 256x256 at 72dpi and saved for web as a png-24  but its not working.  Are there special steps im missing in creating png images for openGL textures?